# Using an ARRAYFORMULA that contains FILTERs in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to calculate the weighted average of some data for each person `B3:B` on a list. I pull in the values and weights from a separate sheet based on a filter to match the person in that row of my current sheet, and not include null data.

This is the formula to calculate a single person's weighted average:
`=AVERAGE.WEIGHTED(FILTER(Form!$G$2:$G, Form!$C$2:$C = $B3, Form!$J$2:$J <> ""), FILTER(Form!$J$2:$J, Form!$C$2:$C = $B3, Form!$J$2:$J <> ""))`

But trying to Array it to avoid having the formula in every cell of the column still only gives me the first weighted average.
`=ARRAYFORMULA(AVERAGE.WEIGHTED(FILTER(Form!$G$2:$G, Form!$C$2:$C = $B3:B, Form!$J$2:$J <> ""), FILTER(Form!$J$2:$J, Form!$C$2:$C = $B3:B, Form!$J$2:$J <> "")))`

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: AVERAGE.WEIGHTED & FILTER are not supported under ARRAYFORMULA

Comment: Can you please provide a sample sheet which contains a sample input and your expected output? [Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(B2:B,QUERY(QUERY(Form!C:J,"select C,G*J,J where J is not null",1),"select Col1,sum(Col2)/sum(Col3) group by Col1",1),2,FALSE))`

1. Compute the weighted value of each line with the first `QUERY`
2. Compute the weighted average of each person with second `QUERY`
3. Do `ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP` on the output